# A dialog box in winapi

Tags: winapi

I've got a slight problem with my dialog box. it shows its contents in the parent windows. instead of a different frame, nothing seems to be wrong. I used the DS_MODALFRAME and the WS_ styles but it isn't working

END

This is the dialog procedure

```
BOOL CALLBACK AboutDialog(HWND fsr_win,UINT f_msg, WPARAM fwParam, LPARAM flParam)
{
    switch (f_msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(fwParam)
        {
        case ID_OK:
            EndDialog(fsr_win,TRUE);
            return TRUE;
            break;
        };
        return TRUE;

    };
    return TRUE;
}



1 RT_MANIFEST "File searcher 2.exe.Manifest"

FSR_ABOUT DIALOG FIXED 6, 21, 100,100
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME
CAPTION "About Generic"

FONT 10, "MS Shell Dlg"
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "&Okay", ID_OK, 40, 80, 40, 10
    LTEXT           "File searcher", 104, 10, 20,90, 
8
    LTEXT           "Copyright © DONSN® 2014 ", 107, 10,40,90, 8
END




B
```

Comment: Did you specify WS_CHILD style? If so, this is a reason.

Comment: Can you make your question title more clear? Can you post the code you used to create your dialog box?

Comment: It's impossible to tell you why your code is not working when *you don't post the code*. "it isn't working" is also not a meaningful problem description unless you explain *specifically* what "not working" means.

Comment: @Ken White, I guess this is the problem: "it shows its contents in the parent windows".

Comment: @Daniel donsn, Could you please provide part of code that opens the dialog box? please?

Comment: @kenwhite yes....

DialogBox(fhInstance, "FSR_ABOUT", fsr_win, AboutDialog);

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution was to change a bit of the line of code in the dialog procedure which apparently returns true instead of false...

So we have
{
/* after the case statements*/
Return FALSE
}
 And that's all it shows with a close button...but with the common control stuff on.